# How to run an async Python Event-Hub trigger Azure Function using EventHubConsumerClient class?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, python-asyncio, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to develop an event-hub trigger azure function that could receive events from a first event-hub and send these events to a second event-hub.
As additional features **I'd like my function to be asynchronous and use store checkpoints in an Azure Blob Storage**.
To do so, I wanted to use the **EventHubConsumerClient class of the azure-eventhub library** (https://pypi.org/project/azure-eventhub/, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/event-hubs/eventhubconsumerclient?view=azure-node-latest)

However, it seems I cannot receive the events in the first place when I'm testing the function locally on VSCode.

The Event Hub I am listening has two partitions. Its shared access policy is set to send and listen.
I have a small script to send him messages for testing and it works great.
My Azure function runtime is 4.x with python 3.9.13 with locally a conda base.

Here is the code of my function to receive the events with EventHubConsumerClient class in my **init**.py:

```
import logging
import asyncio
import os
from azure.eventhub.aio import EventHubConsumerClient
from azure.eventhub.extensions.checkpointstoreblobaio import BlobCheckpointStore
import azure.functions as func

CONNECTION_STR = os.environ.get("EVENT_HUB_CONN_STR")
EVENTHUB_NAME = os.environ.get("EVENT_HUB_NAME")
STORAGE_CONNECTION_STR = os.environ.get("AZURE_STORAGE_CONN_STR")
BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME = os.environ.get("AZURE_STORAGE_NAME")


async def on_event(partition_context, event):
    logging.info("Received event with body: {} from partition: {}.".format(event.body_as_str(encoding="UTF-8"), partition_context.partition_id))
    await partition_context.update_checkpoint(event)


async def receive(client):
    await client.receive(
        on_event=on_event,
        starting_position="-1",  # "-1" is from the beginning of the partition.
    )


async def main(one_event: func.EventHubEvent):
    checkpoint_store = BlobCheckpointStore.from_connection_string(STORAGE_CONNECTION_STR, BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME)
    client = EventHubConsumerClient.from_connection_string(
        CONNECTION_STR,
        consumer_group="$Default",
        eventhub_name=EVENTHUB_NAME,
        checkpoint_store=checkpoint_store,
    )
    async with client:
        await receive(client)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

source: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub/samples/async_samples/recv_with_checkpoint_store_async.py

Note: I know the one_event in main is not used in the main code but I want him to behave as a trigger to run main.

My function.json file is:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventHubTrigger",
      "name": "one_event",
      "direction": "in",
      "eventHubName": "<My_event_hub_name>",
      "connection": "<My_event_hub_co_str>",
      "cardinality": "one",
      "consumerGroup": "$Default"
    }
  ]
}
```

I defined an event hub input binding in there to use as a trigger.

I also have a local.settings.json which contains some variables and the requirements.txt which does not seem to lack any libraries.

FYI: I have tested another method (here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-python) (without using EventHubConsumerClient class) to receive the events and it works fine but I do not have the checkpoint and async capabilities.

Upon running the function locally with a "func start", instead of receiving and printing some basic information about the received event, I've got a lot of messages continuously printing in my terminal.
**It keeps on printing and it locks my terminal** so I've got to manually kill it and create a new one.

So it seems that my code is not working properly.

*I am probably messing things up about the main() and asyncio.run() methods.
*
Do you know by any chance what the problem may be please?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a Python expert, but on a conceptual level I can tell that when using the regular event hub trigger, [checkpointing still takes places](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/serverless/event-hubs-functions/performance-scale#checkpointing), using [a storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azurewebjobsstorage):

> **AzureWebJobsStorage**
>
> The Azure Functions runtime uses this storage account connection string for normal operation. Some uses of this storage account include key management, timer trigger management, and **Event Hubs checkpoints.** The storage account must be a general-purpose one that supports blobs, queues, and tables

Under the hood, the trigger uses an [EventProcessorHost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/event-driven-scaling#event-hubs-trigger), which is similar to the `EventHubConsumerClient` (I suppose the azure function runtime will get updated soon to also use the EventHubConsumerClient).

So, I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. It seems like you have combined an event hub triggered function with your own event hub listener. The `EventHubConsumerClient` you are using will wait for new event hub messages to arrive and blocks further execution untill explicitly stopped. That is not going to work for an azure function, which execution time should be short and is limited to 5 minutes by default. If you would have a continuous running azure web job for example, using a `EventHubConsumerClient` would make sense.

> I'm trying to develop an event-hub trigger azure function that could receive events from a first event-hub and send these events to a second event-hub.

I would say you need an [event hub triggered function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-python) with an [Event Hub output binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-output?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-python) to pass messages from one event hub to another.

Comment: Thank you for answer, your point about the checkpoint made me reconsider the need I had of the class I wanted to use. Very enlightening, thank you!